# Automating Amazon EBS snapshots anyone have a good script or solution for this on linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I'd expect this to be fairly routine, but cannot find a simple approach for creating an managing EBS snapshots automatically.

Was hoping there'd be a shceduler in the AWS console.. alas not yet.

Would appreciate any suggestions as to how best to do this on from Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: Another excellent question closed as "not constructive"

Comment: Yeah, I don't get it either.  So it isn't exactly a great question, but it still has a lot of value.  Throwing the baby out with the bath water, if you ask me...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can easily script something to do this for you.

1. setup [the EC2 commandline API tools](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=351)
2. set `EC2_CERT` and `EC2_PRIVATE_KEY` in order to be able to use the API tools
3. parse the results of `ec2-describe-snapshots`
4. delete the appropriate snapshots

The results look something like:

```
SNAPSHOT    snap-xxxxxxxx   vol-xxxxxxxx    completed   2009-08-26T07:39:33+0000    100%
```

You can then do some parsing of the dates and sorting and start removing the older snapshots.

NOTE: I don't know if we can trust the sort order but I've never seen it sort any other way than oldest to newest.

To delete a snapshot, use `ec2-delete-snapshot snap-xxxxxxxx`.

The rest I leave to you as a simple Bash script that you can call daily or however often you need from cron.

Comment: One can always use 'sort' to ensure the sort order like: "ec2-describe-snapshots | sort -k 5"

Answer (score 23):

Take a look at AWS missing tools and especially to https://github.com/colinbjohnson/aws-missing-tools/tree/master/ec2-automate-backup This does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I found this, hope it helps:

```
ec2-describe-snapshots | sort -r -k 5 | sed 1,6d | awk '{print "Deleting snapshot: " $2}'; system("ec2-delete-snapshot " $2)'
```

See: [Bulk Delete EBS Snapshots From the Command Line (A Howto).](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?messageID=109517)

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug, but - you can give Ebs2s3 a go:
https://github.com/ajmfulcher/ebs2s3

Rails app to automate snapshot creation and prune old snapshots.  Introduction and some screenshots here:
http://ajmfulcher.blogspot.com/2011/04/ebs2s3-automated-backup-for-amazon-ebs.html

Answer (score 0):

A wonderful script to create an automatic snapshots.

https://github.com/rakesh-sankar/Tools/blob/master/AmazonAWS/EBS/EBS-Snapshot.sh

Just copy the code and create a file, then add a cronjob whenever you want it to run.