# automated backup script of ec2 snapshots to s3 bucket

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services

How can we automated the process or is there any shell script available where we  can take the back of ec2 ami and move them to s3 bucket on daily basis.

Comment: You can't access the data inside an EC2 snapshot without creating an EBS volume from that snapshot. Once you have created the EBS volume and attached it to a server then you would be able to run something like `aws s3 sync` to copy it to S3.

Comment: @MarkB is correct, but I am curious: What is your motivation for wanting to do this?

Comment: Hi i am looking to take backup of my ec2 instances and use them if i need them in case of emergency.

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy the snapshots to s3, store them as snapshots.  There are lots of ways of automating this, see [Automating Amazon EBS snapshots anyone have a good script or solution for this on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320994/automating-amazon-ebs-snapshots-anyone-have-a-good-script-or-solution-for-this-o) for some suggestions

We use a commercial product, [cloud protection manager (CPM)](http://www.n2ws.com/)

The cost of snapshot storage is higher typically 0.10 / GB month for EBS snapshots vs. 0.039 GB / month for S3